# About the 'compare' function in c++

Tags: c++, string, compare

I want to compare two strings and count how many sub-string B can be found in string A.

But it always show '0'. What's wrong?

```
int getMatchCount(string a, string b)
{
    int num;
    num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length() - b.length() + 1; ++i)
    {
        if (a.compare(i, b.length() + i, b, 0, b.length()) == 0) // comapre function
        {
            num = num + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int x = getMatchCount("sisisisisisisisis", "si");
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: How long is your string a and b?

Comment: A is 5, B is 2..

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but you don't need the else part of your if/else statement. It will continue by default since there is no additional code in the for loop. Also `num = num + 1` can be shortened to `num += 1`

Comment: so what should i do? The 'compare' function can't solve my problem?

Answer (score 4):

1. `b.length() + i` is wrong, the length to be compared is `b.length()`.
2. You don't need to `continue`.
3. You need to return the value.
4. `i < a.length() - b.length();` will count 3 for a = "sisisisi", b = "si", but `i <= a.length() - b.length();` will count 4.

```
int getMatchCount(string a, string b)
{
    int num;
    num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length() - b.length(); i++) {
        if (a.compare(i, b.length(), b, 0, b.length()) == 0) {
            num = num + 1;
        }
    }

    return num;
}

int main()
{
    int x = getMatchCount("sisisisisisisisis", "si");
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome! and also forgot to mention that `i < a.length() - b.length();` will not count last match, but `i <= a.length() - b.length();` will do.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the form of `std::string::compare()` you are trying to use is

> int compare (size_t pos, size_t len, const string& str,
>                size_t subpos, size_t sublen) const;

The second parameter should be number of characters you want to compare.

```
 if (a.compare(i, b.length(), b, 0, b.length()) == 0)
```

See [working code](https://ideone.com/RTClg9) which outputs `8` as expected.
Also don't forget to `return num` at the end as pointed out by @Gabor